# The fastest algorithm of computing Principal eigenvector of a non-negative-entries matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I am studying the QR algorithm, is it the fastest one in this situation?

Comment: (Principal, not principle.)

Comment: @Hans Thanks! Corrected.

Comment: Nothing *else* special about your matrix? There's power iteration if you already have a good estimate...

Comment: @J.M. In fact the matrix is a 0-or-1-matrix, all entries are either 0 or 1.

Comment: Oh, $0$ is positive... you really should have mentioned that you had a $0$-$1$ matrix to begin with...

Comment: @J.M. to be precise it should be a non-negative entries matrix. Topic updated